# ant install prefix

Tags: ant

This is my first time using *ant* and I can't for the life of me figure out how to tell where I want it to install files. I'm looking for something similar to `./configure --prefix=< PLACE I WANT IT INSTALLED INTO >`

Running:

```
ant package
```

installs it into `./build/dist/`.

I've searched but can't figure out what to pass in that'll tell it where to install to.  It's driving me nuts!

Comment: ant can be used to build plenty of languages, why is *this* question tagged Java?

Answer (score 2):

Bah!  After examining the build.xml file I guessed (correctly) that this would do the trick:

ant -Dtarget.dir=/my/install/dir package